# Passing lists between pages

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to pass list of objects between pages in my app.

Right now, I've something like this:

```
List<AB> abs = new List<AB>();

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    abs.Clear();

    foreach (var obj in e.Parameter as List<AB>)
    {
        abs.Add(dupa);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work at all. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

OK! because I've found an answer for my question i'm posting it for the future.

First i've aded a public list in app.cs

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    public List<AB> absList = new List<AB>();

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }
}
```

Later in page cs file, simply call it like

```
foreach(var dupa in ((App)Application.Current).absList)
{
    CB.Items.Add(dupa.name);
}
```

Where CB is name of combobox

Comment: You don't have to add it to the app.cs file. You can just create it in a new class file and implement a singleton to acces the file from wherever you want. http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: @Daniel thank You sir for more info! i will check it for sure :)